# How can handler get information from raise PermissionDenied('info') exception?

Tags: django, django-views

Django allow custom error handlers, like `handler403` for handling of "Permission Denied" errors.  This error can be raised with:

```
from django.core.exceptions import PermissionDenied
...
raise PermissionDenied('info')
```

The handler can then be:

```
def error_403_permission_denied(request):
    ...
```

How can the handler get access to the information given when raising the `PermissionDenied` exception, for example the `'info'` string above, in order to show this as part of the HTML generated for the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is possible currently. There was a [ticket that was fixed in Django 1.9](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24733) that addresses this limitation - so from Django 1.9 you [will be able](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/views/#the-403-http-forbidden-view) to accept an `exception` argument in your view.

Comment: Thanks, so I can stop looking in my current 1.8.4 version ;-)